# Search data on basis of month and date Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

```
select * from table where 1 and DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn,"%d-%m") BETWEEN "01-09" and "30-09"
```

This query is returning all the data. I just want the data between these dates, without taking into account the year.

In the table dateColumn is yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the comparison as MM-DD, not DD-MM:

```
select *
from table
where DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '09-01' and '09-30'
```

Or, for this case, you could just do:

```
where month(dateColumn) = 9
```

Comment: Date filter is also required not only month. Like i want data between 1 and 15 of the month.

Comment: @DanishKundra . . . The first query should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  MONTH(dateColumn) = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the month is September

```
select * from table where DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn,"%m")
= '09
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows from your table where the month of your  date is 9 and the day of month is between 1 and 30, you can actually do this quite easy and more explicit:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table t
WHERE
    MONTH(t.date) = 9 and
    DAY(t.date) BETWEEN 1 and 30
```

It's also easier to understand.